# Post não sobe para o arquivo php (php + html - Não encontro o erro)

Tags: php, html

Eu não consigo fazer com que o post seja subido a página `enviarmsg.php`, 
erro que ocorre: "enviarmsg.php on line 3".

Esse é somente o pedaço com problema, o site em si é muito grande para upar tudo.

**Formulário da entrada de dados:**

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                     
                        <div class="row">
                                <form action="enviarmsg.php" method="POST" >
                            <div class="col-md-6">  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_contato" placeholder="Digite seu nome *"  required data-validation-required-message="Por favor digite seu nome.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_contato" placeholder="Digite seu Email *"  required data-validation-required-message="Por favor digite seu email.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefone_contato" placeholder="Digite Seu telefone *"  required data-validation-required-message="Por favor digite seu telefone DDD 0000-0000.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="msg_contato" placeholder="Escreva sua Mensagem *"  required data-validation-required-message="Por favor escreva sua mensagem."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                           <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                 <div id="success"></div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> &nbsp;
                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Limpar"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        </div> 
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

**PHP que recebe os códigos:**

```html
<?php
 
$nome = $_POST['nome_contato'];
$email = $_POST['email_contato'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone_contato'];
$mensagem = $_POST['msg_contato'];
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

// Compo E-mail
  $arquivo = "
  <style type='text/css'>
  body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family:Verdane;
  font-size:12px;
  color: #666666;
  }
  a{
  color: #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  </style>
    <html>
        <table width='510' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <tr>
              <td>
  <tr>
                 <td width='500'>Nome:$nome</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width='320'>E-mail:<b>$email</b></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
                  <td width='320'>Telefone:<b>$telefone</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width='320'>Mensagem:$mensagem</td>
                </tr>
            </td>
          </tr>  
          <tr>
            <td>Este e-mail foi enviado em <b>$data_envio</b> às <b>$hora_envio</b></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </html>
  ";
//enviar
   
  // emails para quem será enviado o formulário
  $emailenviar = "guilherme_ribeiro11@hotmail.com";
  $destino = $emailenviar;
  $assunto = "Contato pelo Site";
 
  // É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'From: $nome <$email>';
  //$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailPadrao\r\n";
   
  $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
  if($enviaremail){
  $mgm = "E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO! <br> O link será enviado para o e-mail fornecido no formulário";
  echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;URL=contato.php'>";
  } else {
  $mgm = "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
  echo "";
  }
?>
```

O intuito deste código é enviar o e-mail com os dados e o formato certo.

Comment: A que se refere cada um desses códigos?

Comment: primeiro codigo é o form onde os dados entrar e o segundo é o php que recebem os codigos , intuito deste codigo é enviar o email com os dados e o formato certo.

Answer (score 0):

não tem erro na linha 3, mas achei 4 erros no seu código:

1. O nome, na linha 62, não imprime o valor da variável, e sim seu nome `$nome`
2. O e-mail, também na linha 62, não imprime o valor da variável, e sim o `$email`
3. Não exibe mensagem de sucesso, pois não há o `echo`, na linha 68
4. Não exibe mensagem de falha, pois não há o `echo`, na linha 70

[image: correcao no codigo]

Transcrição:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome_contato'];
$email = $_POST['email_contato'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone_contato'];
$mensagem = $_POST['msg_contato'];
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

// Compo E-mail
  $arquivo = "
  <style type='text/css'>
  body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family:Verdane;
  font-size:12px;
  color: #666666;
  }
  a{
  color: #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  </style>
    <html>
        <table width='510' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <tr>
              <td>
  <tr>
                 <td width='500'>Nome:$nome</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width='320'>E-mail:<b>$email</b></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
                  <td width='320'>Telefone:<b>$telefone</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width='320'>Mensagem:$mensagem</td>
                </tr>
            </td>
          </tr>  
          <tr>
            <td>Este e-mail foi enviado em <b>$data_envio</b> às <b>$hora_envio</b></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </html>
  ";
//enviar

  // emails para quem será enviado o formulário
  $emailenviar = "comercial@ecowebdesign.com.br";
  $destino = $emailenviar;
  $assunto = "Contato pelo Site";

  // É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'From: '.$nome.' <'.$email.'>';
  //$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailPadrao\r\n";

  $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
  if($enviaremail){
  $mgm = "E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO! <br> O link será enviado para o e-mail fornecido no formulário";
  echo $msgm." <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;URL=contato.php'>";
  } else {
  $mgm = $msm."ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
  echo "";
  }
?>
```

**Mais importante que isso**

Não é recomendado disparar e-mails sem autenticação, pois vários servidores podem recusar seu e-mail ou simplesmente marcar como spam, recomendo utilizar a Biblioteca https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, configure o SMTP e faça seus disparos de forma correta e segura.

Abs